# Expand/collapse ttk Treeview branch

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I would like to know the command for collapsing and expanding a branch in ttk.Treeview.

Here is a minimalistic example code:

```
#! coding=utf-8
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)

tree.insert("", index="end",iid="Main", text="main branch")
tree.insert("Main", index="end", text="Stuff 1")
tree.insert("Main", index="end", text="Stuff 2")

root.mainloop()
```

What command opens and/or expands the "main branch"? There has to be one, since these are called when clicking the plus and minus signs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For me (Win 7, Py2.7), your example comes up with the branch closed, but you can open or close it as you like with this command:

```
tree.item("Main", open=False)
```

Set it to False to close it.

See these topics:

[25.2. tkinter.ttk - Tk themed widgets - Item options](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#item-options)

[25.2. tkinter.ttk - Tk themed widgets - item method](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.item)

Item options can be set either with `insert()`, or after the fact with `item()`.